# What is the meaning of the "Application Requires iPhone Environment" key in info.plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, applet, info.plist

I'm having trouble understanding the specific requirements in the `info.plist` file in my app. Should I change it at all, or are the default settings typically the "correct" options?

Specifically, the entry: **APPLICATION REQUIRES IPHONE ENVIRONMENT**

If set to yes, does that imply only an **iPhone** is capable of running my app, meaning an iPod Touch or iPad won't be able to run the app?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Here's [Apple's documentation on the "LSRequiresiPhoneOS" bits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW2) of an application's info.plist file.

Basically all it means is that the app is designed to run under iOS.  This flag should be set to YES no matter if the target device is an iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad.

Who knows, maybe in the not-so-distant future, MacOS will be able to run iOS apps (or vice versa)?

Comment: or (speculating) Apple TV could get in the mix there

Comment: Today I archive my app and it was giving me `.pkg` file so I added this key and now I added this key so that I could archive it as `.ipa` file (xcode 6.0.1)

Comment: Isn't this an artifact of the very early days of "iPhoneOS", when iPods were sold without it, but could be upgraded to iPhoneOS, and allow them to use the *new* App Store?  I don't think it's about  **future** possibilities.

Comment: ^ Seems more likely given the oddly misleading name. I'd imagine everyone landed here because they were worried this meant their application wouldn't work on an iPad

Comment: Nice prediction there :)

Comment: And it's 2020 and we now know ARM MacBooks will be able to run iOS apps ;)