# Can't read PKZip signature validating app for App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am attempting to submit a new version of my app to the App Store.

I am using Xcode 6 GM.  The previous version of this app was submitted with Xcode 5.1 without issue.

After I generate the app archive, I click "Validate..." in the organiser.  Xcode takes me through the process of selecting my developer team and verifies the provisioning profile that will be used.

It then starts to generate the package before failing with the message

> ditto: Couldn't read PKZip Signature
>   Unable to extract archive.  Please make sure /var/....path to .pkg  is a valid zip or ipa archive.

I have navigated to the directory and tried zip on the command line - this gives an error.  If I rename the file to .zip then Finder is happy to unzip it, but Zipeg also returns an error.

What I have tried:

- Build->Clean
- Recreated the provisioning profile
- Recreated my signing certificate
- Checked all of the "code signing" settings are the same as for my other projects that work

I have also looked into the log files that are created by the packaging process and there is nothing untoward listed until the error about the invalid zip file.

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I have received details of a work-around from Apple developer support.

1. Open your target's Info.plist
2. Select an entry in the plist and then select "Show raw keys & values" from the Editor menu
3. Ensure the key "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" has the value "YES" (add it if necessary)
4. Regenerate your archive and submit

Comment: Works, now there is no validation issue nor ipa issue.

Comment: Note that "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" is case sensitive.

Comment: 2. Select an entry in the plist and then RIGHT CLICK and then select "Show raw keys & values" from the Editor menu

Comment: That is an alternate method if you don't want to use the Editor menu in the menu bar

Comment: Yes, even though it mentions 'iPhone' it is required for iPad as well - my app was iPad only and I couldn't validate until I added this key

Comment: So what do I put if I want both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: This is the key you need regardless of whether your app is iPhone, iPad or universal (both)

Comment: Oh ok great thanks. I just found that out here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904039/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-application-requires-iphone-environment-key-in-info. Too bad this key didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Awesome solved my problem! Yes, right-click on an entry to show raw values, or you can navigate to the file itself and "open with external editor".

Comment: Is there a solution for creating an OSX app? I get the same thing, but I am not trying to build for iOS.

Comment: I can't help you directly - You can have a look through the build logs to see if you can see something obvious, but you may need to log an incident with developer support.  They took around 24 hrs to get me an answer.  Perhaps check that `requires iPhone os` isn't present?