# Xcode 6.01 Archive Validation failed: "ditto: counldn't read PKZip signature"

Tags: xcode, archive

I build a new project for iOS8 and tried to make the archive validation. This failed with error: Xcode 6.01 Archive Validation failed: "ditto: counldn't read PKZip signature"

I tried everything to rebuild, clean etc. but this has no effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate question....See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758669/cant-read-pkzip-signature-validating-app-for-app-store